# Invalid block type magento2

Tags: magento2

```
[2016-02-06 12:00:12] main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Invalid block type: Newibnab\CategoriesSide\Block\CategorisCollection' in C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block.php:262
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block.php(237): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance('Newibnab\\Catego...', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block.php(216): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock('Newibnab\\Catego...', 'categoriecollec...', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'categoriecollec...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Config.php(166): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Config.php(475): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Interceptor.php(323): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getElementAttribute('body', 'class')
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Config.php(433): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Interceptor->getElementAttribute('body', 'class')
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Interceptor.php(297): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->addBodyClass('catalog-product...')
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Product\View.php(159): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Interceptor->addBodyClass('catalog-product...')
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Product\View.php(214): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View->initProductLayout(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Controller\Product\View.php(109): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View->prepareAndRender(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), 5, Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject))
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\var\generation\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View->execute()
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->execute()
#19 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'designLoader')
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design.php(39): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\module-store\App\Action\Plugin\Context.php(98): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 [internal function]: Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\module-store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 [internal function]: Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#34 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#35 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 [internal function]: Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#38 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#39 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\module-tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 [internal function]: Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#42 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#43 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\module-weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 [internal function]: Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#46 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\var\generation\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#47 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#48 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#50 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#51 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#52 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\module-store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor.php(89): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#53 [internal function]: Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#54 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#55 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#56 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#57 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#58 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#59 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCookieVali...')
#60 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie.php(78): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#61 [internal function]: Magento\Store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#62 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#63 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#64 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#65 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#66 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#67 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#68 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#69 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#70 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#71 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#72 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#73 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#74 C:\xampp\htdocs\flower\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#75 {main} [] []
```

Answer (score 1):

very little Information :P

my guess: Typo in the Block Class Name (Missing e in Categories)

There is a Magento2 Plugin for phpstorm which can validate the Class Names in layout and configuration files:

https://github.com/dkvashninbay/magento2plugin

Comment: I have removed this block from code folder than its giving error

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a cache/generation issue, try to:

- Remove [magento_root]/var/cache
- Remove [magento_root]/var/generation
- Remove [magento_root]/var/view_processed
- Remove [magento_root]/var/di

I problem persist remove too:

- Remove [magento_root]/pub/static/frontend/*

BTW: A little more information about what have you tried would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you remove block Name "CategorisCollection" but you forget to remove its dependency or call from somewhere. Search "CategorisCollection" this in all your code.Remove it if you find then clear cache and delete var/generation.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a chance is very high that you have just executed the "upgrade command" . remove "code" folder from "generated" folder to solve this issue.